# Error provision cassandra with playbook ansible.(Vagrant VM)

Tags: cassandra, ansible

I'm trying to install and provision(using Ansible) Cassandra in a virtual machine but i have the follow issue:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true,
>   "msg":"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'SimpleSnitch' is undefined"}

this issue occrus in the fifth task: **"Change /etc/cassandra.yaml"**

The file .yml is like this:

```
- name: "add datastax cassandra debian repository"
  apt_repository: repo='deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main'

- name: "Add datastax repo key"
  apt_key: url=http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key

- name: "Install cassandra"
  apt: name=dsc30 state=latest update_cache=yes install_recommends=yes

- name: "Install cassandra-tools"
  apt: name=cassandra-tools state=latest update_cache=yes install_recommends=yes

- name: "Change /etc/cassandra.yaml"
  template: src=cassandra.yaml.j2 dest=/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

- name: "Restart cassandra"
  service: name=cassandra state=restarted

- name: stop cassandra
  service: name=cassandra state=stopped

- name: clear test data
  shell: rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*

- name: clear test data
  shell: rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_data/*

- name: start cassandra
  service: name=cassandra state=started

- name: "Stop to back the Cassandra node"
  pause: seconds=30
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error usually means that you forgot to wrap a string in quotes. The problem isn't in the playbook file you've pasted though. Somewhere else you're setting some kind of snitch variable used by the cassandra.yaml.j2 template, and you have forgotten to wrap the "SimpleSnitch" value in quotes so ansible is mistakenly interpreting it as an undefined variable name.

Also, even for dev-clusters there's generally no reason not to get into the habit of using Gossiping Property File snitch. It's very simple to configure and will put you in a good position to migrate your config to a prod cluster someday.

Answer (score 0):

In your **cassandra.yaml.j2** file, you are using a variable **SimpleSnitch** at **endpoint_snitch:** section. For that reason you are having this error:
`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg":"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'SimpleSnitch' is undefined"}`

Comment: So, what is exactly the variable "endpoint_snitch" ? And what I should put it?

Comment: You can directly assign the value for "endpoint_snitch" at "cassandra.yaml".
For 'SimpleSnitch' configuration, just put "endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch" at "cassandra.yaml" file. No need to use an extra variable for this one.

Comment: It's works,thanks dude...I also found a link with a good explanation of how to configure an cassandra.yaml file, I will post here as answer to the others guys with same issue. Thank you!